# How can I make a rectangle in pygame be able to check for other rectangles around it?

Tags: python, pygame

As part of my current pygame project (I am very new to pygame), I have created multiple rectangles that move at random around the screen. As one of the features of this game, I want to make it so if one rectangle is close enough to another one, it moves towards it. Another feature I want to add is that rectangles cannot collide with each other, but I don't want to just do the regular

```
if rectangle1.colliderect(rectangle2):
    rectange.x -= 10  # That is, it's previous position
```

because it will make the animations look odd.

The main way I can see to solve these problems is to use some sort of function that could check if a rectangle.x - 30 is another rectangle (or something similar), but I am unaware of one that exists.

I have attempted to look through google, but I haven't found anything as all the posts are different problems that aren't quite the same.

Thank you for any responses!

Comment: 1/ If rectangles get close, they move toward one another. 2/ They cannot collide. That seems like contradicory requirements to me.

Comment: you could try creating a rectangle that is slightly larger than the rectangle you want to check collision for, and don't render it, use it to collide with other rectangles around it.

Comment: @paxdiablo I would have those 2 things happen under different conditions, think of them as 2 separate things I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`inflate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate) to create a rectangle that is larger than the original one and surrounds it. Use this rectangle to find other rectangles in range:

```py
test_rect = rect1.inflate(dist, dist)
if test_rect.colliderect(rect2):
    # [...]
```